# How to find Base Station Identifying Code (BSIC)

Tags: android, telephony

Is it possible to find Base Station Identifying Code in android. To clarify, Let 'A' calls to 'B'. Before 'B' receive the phone call, his installed app will find
'A's BSIC and match it with a given database of BSIC( this BSIC database may be located on phone locally or
in a web or from phone network provider's database ) then will find 'A' location( Say +88017... is calling from "Dinajpur of Bangladesh" ).Is it possible ? if so how ? please help me...

Answer (score 2):

**Rereading the question, you want the other person's tower, not your own. No, i don't think that info is available to you. At most, you can guess by the country and region codes.**

---

Not relevant anymore:

I believe you can achieve what you want getting the **cell id** in use or all the neighboring cells

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation loc = (GsmCellLocation) mTelephonyManager.getCellLocation(); 
Log.d ("CID", Integet.toString(loc.getCid()));
Log.d ("LAC", Integet.toString(loc.getLac()));
// or 
List<NeighboringCellInfo> list = mTelephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo ();
for (NeighboringCellInfo cell : list) {
    Log.d ("CID", Integet.toString(cell.getCid()));
    Log.d ("LAC", Integet.toString(cell.getLac()));
}
```

You can refer then to cell location through several open databases (e.g., http://www.location-api.com/ or http://opencellid.org/ )

If this is not enought, I suggest you to check this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/b55c8d3275ed7042/78d9c30c49e94a3a , specially this link: http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/27_series/27.007/27007-860.zip